# Hotkeys for Word 365 for changing font colors?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, ms-office, office-365

I would like to assign some hotkeys to switching font colors in word on my macbook. I just need something to toggle between red and black color. I went to `Tools->Customize Keyboard0->Fonts`, but I don't see an option to set hotkeys for Font Colors, only for font type.

Does anyone know know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options for changing font colors are a bit unclear but as I understand it, once you are in *Customize Keyboard* go to:

`Categories: Format > Commands: Color: > Color (menu) and select the color you want`

Click on the "Assign" button and press your preferred keyboard shortcut. As long as the shortcut you want isn't already assigned to another command it will be allowed. There are about a dozen named colors for you to choose from.

Comment: This works! Below "Color", is something called "FontColor" (which I originally thought was what you were referring to). Any clue what that one is for? I tried setting a hotkey for it, but when I pressed it nothing happens, so I'm ont sure what it's for

Comment: Sorry, no idea what that is for